# Docker with systemd and systemctl

Tags: linux, docker, systemd, systemctl

I want to make a docker container that can run systemctl and systemd commands.
I am new to docker and never have I ever learnt about docker.
I have a docker file but dont know where should i place what.

[Here is my docker file](https://pastebin.com/FEvkkA6E) `Link to pastebin` , if someone can help me understand what command and where should i place it in this dockerfile so that i can just deploy this from github into my vps and have systemctl and systemd .

I saw this thread and seriously don't know where should i put what.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297226/how-to-run-systemctl-command-inside-docker-container

Comment: Systemd needs dbus which is too much for docker. Do you really need such a fat container? Consider using something like https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: systemd does not require dbus as long as you execute the systemctl command as root user. But it is not heavy either compared to systemd itself.

Comment: D-Bus isn't inherently "heavy" (it's a very simple message bus), but if you find dbus-daemon problematic, dbus-broker is an alternative. I'm wondering though, is Docker even suitable for this kind of container? My understanding is that it was only meant for "one job per container" individual services, not whole nested OSes – you'd use nspawn or lxc for those...

Comment: How can I execute - systemctl start docker inside a docker container. I'm using a docker-in-docker. I want to start the docker but it gives error related to systemd (PID 1 ) init user.